# simple regex matching

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex expression that generates a match and strips off the $, and the last two characters, if the last character ends in a capital letter plus a number.

```
I'll strip off the $ and then an ending capital letter + number:

$mytestA1 --> expected output: mytest
$againD4 --> expected output: again
$something --> expected output: something
$name3 --> expected output: name3 // because there was no capital letter before the number digit
$name2P4 --> expected output: name2
```

I'll have an 'if' check in my code that checks for the existence of a $ before I would even bother to run the regex.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the space in 'my test' a typo? Also, which language do you use?

Comment: the description is a bit unclear - can you post examples of the expected output

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I added in the expected output.  Using Java to run the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java just use String#replaceAll:

```
String replaced = str.replaceAll("^\\$|[A-Z]\\d$", "");
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer, this was the simplest one.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient but it will work...

```
\$([^\s]*)(?:[A-Z]\d)|\$([^\s]*)
```

It works because the first set finds all those that have the Capitol followed by number... and the second one finds all the ones without the suffix...

If you get the matches from the capture group that is what you want.

I think something like this would work...

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HereYouGo {
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        String input = "$mytestA1 --> expected output: mytest\r\n$againD4 --> expected output: again\r\n$something --> expected output: something\r\n$name3 --> expected output: name3 // because there was no capital letter before the number digit\r\n$name2P4 --> expected output: name2\r\n";      

        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("\\$([^ ]*)(?:[A-Z]\\d)|\\$([^ ]*)", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);

        Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(input);

        while(myMatcher.find())
        {
            String group1 = myMatcher.group(1);
            String group2 = myMatcher.group(2);

            //note: this should probably be changed in the case neither match is found
            System.out.println( group1!=null? group1 : group2 );
        }
    }
}
```

this will output the following

```
mytest
again
something
name3
name2
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  The problem with this answer is that if you input "$name3", it returns "nam", when I'm expecting "name" because the 'e' is not a capital letter.  For reference, I'm using this testing tool.  I'm not sure if it's 100% reliable - http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: I tested using RegexBuddy and using the Java regex engine and it works just fine.

Comment: I think you had case insensitive on... ;-)